# Compile Angular component from selector

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app that has a lot of components that are visualizations of RxJS operators like `rx-map`, `rx-filter`, `rx-reduce`, etc. The visualizations work fine themselves. What I would like to do now is allow a user to select which visualization they want to see via router. I can do this by creating a route for each individual component, but there are a lot of them so that would be a lot of manual routes.

I am trying to have Angular use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to do this. I can get this working like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rx-visualizations-app',
  template: '<ng-template #container></ng-template>',
})
export class RxVisualizationsAppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  private componentRef: ComponentRef<{}>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      getComponentFromRoute(),
    );
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

This works and it does display the component properly. The problem is that I have to have a complete list of component routes to component names and also import every one of these, like:

```
switch (route) {
  case 'map': return RxMapComponent
```

While this does work, it doesn't really make for any less work than just creating a route for every individual visualization.

Is there a way to create a component from a selector or otherwise compile a template string in an app and inject that?

Answer (score 0):

You could define all your Rx* components in an NgModule, and dynamically load them with `ngContainerOutlet`. See docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet).

In the simplest case:

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="RxMapComponent"></ng-container>
```

You could also use `ngComponentOutletNgModuleFactory` with ngComponentOutlet to specify an optional module factory that would give you the ability to dynamically load another module, then load a component from that module.

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="RxMapComponent;
                                  ngModuleFactory: myRxModule;"></ng-container>
```

To paramaterize this, you could wrap the above code into a generic WidgetComponent:

```
<widget componentName="RxMapComponent"></widget>
```

Since the component name is a string, you would still need to maintain a mapping from the component name to the component type (Type<any>):

```
case 'RxMapComponent': return RxMapComponent
```

The main benefit to doing this is that you don't have to setup individual routes.

Comment: I guess what I would like is the ability to use the selector since I'm already importing all of the components into the module. Otherwise it would be ideal to load the component asynchronously from the route rather than importing all of them into the module ahead of time